# Maintain order of selected files in FileUpload with AllowMultiple=true

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms, httppostedfile

I have an `<asp:FileUpload>` control with the property AllowMultiple set to true:

```
<asp:fileupload id="FileUpload" runat="server" allowmultiple="true" cssclass="fileUpload btn btn-sm btn-default" onchange="preloadImages()" />

<div class="field col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 immScarpePreview MainPreviewBox">
 <asp:image id="Image1" runat="server" visible="false" cssclass="img-responsive" />
 <asp:button id="ImmButton" runat="server" text="Upload" onclick="ImmButton_Click" cssclass="hidden" />
</div>
```

In my JavaScript function, I simulate a click on the invisible button:

```
<script>
    function preloadImages() {
        $('#<%=ImmButton.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    }
</script>
```

In the code-behind, I save the files to a temporary folder, and I display the uploaded images in the `<asp:Image>` controls:

```
 protected void ImmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                int cont = 0;
                byte[] fileData = null;
                foreach (HttpPostedFile file in FileUpload.PostedFiles)
                {
                    if (cont == 0)
                    {
                        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("immScarpe/tmp/" + file.FileName), fileData);
                        setImage1("immScarpe/tmp/" + file.FileName);
                    }
                    else if (cont == 1)
                    {
                        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("immScarpe/tmp/" + file.FileName), fileData);
                        setImage2("immScarpe/tmp/" + file.FileName);
                    }
                    else if (cont == 2)
                     //and so on...

                    //so on...
                    cont++;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //error writing file
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
 }

 private void setImage1(string image) //all equals for all the 5 images
 {
     Image1.ImageUrl = image;
     Image1.Visible = true;
 }
```

This is working perfectly but I need some help. When I loop through FileUpload.PostedFiles, the order of the selected images is alphabetical I think. I would like to keep the order of the user's selection. Is this possible?

Comment: Not the answer you might be looking for, but you can add a variable that saves the selection order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have bad news, at least if you’re using Windows.

I tested your code using Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Internet Explorer on Windows 10, and I inspected the HTTP POST requests using Telerik Fiddler. I got identical results in all browsers:

- The order of files in the FileUpload.PostedFiles collection is the *same* as in the HTTP request; ASP.NET doesn’t sort the files in the collection.
- The order of files in the HTTP request is the *same* as in the upload control; the browser doesn’t sort the files in the HTTP request. (To see the files in the upload control, I disabled your `preloadImages` function.)
- The order of files in the upload control (as well as in the client-side [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) collection) is *not* necessarily the same as in the **File name** box in the Windows file selection dialog:

  - If I manually type the names of files out of order, then the upload control lists the files in the order in which I typed them, and the FileUpload.PostedFiles collection maintains that order.
  - However, if I select files out of order by Ctrl+clicking them, then the upload control lists the files alphabetically, as does the FileUpload.PostedFiles collection.

In that final case, I assume Windows sorts the files before giving them to the browser. If that’s true, then *the browser never receives the original order of the user's selection*, and so you can’t maintain the order, not even with JavaScript.

If you absolutely must maintain the order of multiple uploaded files, then you probably need to have multiple `<asp:FileUpload>` controls each with `AllowMultiple="False"`.